# Core-nonemptiness-game theory

Tags: game-theory

In the snippet below in the theorem 3.2.6. 
there is given a characterization of the **core** like this:
$NE,IR, RGP$. However, I believe that core might be **empty** so
it doesn't satisfy $NE$. What's wrong here with this ?

[image: game theory]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$NE$ in the theorem $3.2.6$ can be satisfied for all games in question because we are working on $\Gamma$
which is by definition $$\{(N,V)|C(N,V)\neq\emptyset\}.$$